# How can i get an identified number with each groups?

Tags: sorting, date, variables, filter, sas

I want following forms,

```
stnd_y person_id recu_day date      sick_sym   Admission

2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  A          1
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  B          1
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  D          1
2002   100       20020930 02-09-30  B          2
2002   100       20020930 02-09-30  E          2
2002   100       20021002 02-10-02  X          3
2002   100       20021002 02-10-02  W          3
2002   101       20020927 02-09-27  S          1
2002   101       20020927 02-09-27  O          1
2002   101       20020928 02-09-28  C          2
2002   102       20021001 02-10-01  F          1
2002   103       20021003 02-10-03  G          1
2002   104       20021108 02-11-08  H          1
2002   104       20021108 02-11-08  A          1
2002   104       20021112 02-11-12  B          2


proc sort data=a out=a1;
by person_id recu_fr_dt;
data a3;
set a1 ;
by person_id recu_fr_dt;
if first.person_id then adm+1;
run;
```

According to above codes, the results is following, as i don't mean it.

```
stnd_y person_id recu_day date      sick_sym   Admission

2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  A          1
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  B          2
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  D          3
2002   100       20020930 02-09-30  B          4
2002   100       20020930 02-09-30  E          5
2002   100       20021002 02-10-02  X          6
2002   100       20021002 02-10-02  W          7
2002   101       20020927 02-09-27  S          1
2002   101       20020927 02-09-27  O          2
2002   101       20020928 02-09-28  C          3
2002   102       20021001 02-10-01  F          1
2002   103       20021003 02-10-03  G          1
2002   104       20021108 02-11-08  H          1
2002   104       20021108 02-11-08  A          2
2002   104       20021112 02-11-12  B          3
```

At also, I used followings with sas,

```
proc sort data=old out=new;
by person_id recu_day;
data new1;
set new;
retain admission 0;
by person_id recu_day;
if recu_day^=lag(recu_day) and(or) person_id^=lag(person_id) then 
admission+1;
run;
```

And,

```
data new1;
set new ;
by person_id recu_day;
retain adm 0;
if first.person_id and(or) first.recu_day then admission=admission+1;
run;
```

But, those are not working. How can i solve this? Please let me know about this.

Thank you

How could i fix it?

Thank you! :D

Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076468/how-can-i-get-the-identification-number-with-each-groups/

Comment: Please include the code in this question that you're using that generates the incorrect results.

Comment: OK. I did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification to my answer to your previous question.

This time, it adds 1 to the adm variable each time the day changes for a given person_id.  The `retain` statement ensures that the current value is copied for all subsequent rows where the peson_id and recu_day are the same.

```
data have;
input stnd_y person_id recu_day date :yymmdd8. sick_sym $ Admission;
datalines;
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  A          1
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  B          1
2002   100       20020929 02-09-29  D          1
2002   100       20020930 02-09-30  B          2
2002   100       20020930 02-09-30  E          2
2002   100       20021002 02-10-02  X          3
2002   100       20021002 02-10-02  W          3
2002   101       20020927 02-09-27  S          1
2002   101       20020927 02-09-27  O          1
2002   101       20020928 02-09-28  C          2
2002   102       20021001 02-10-01  F          1
2002   103       20021003 02-10-03  G          1
2002   104       20021108 02-11-08  H          1
2002   104       20021108 02-11-08  A          1
2002   104       20021112 02-11-12  B          2
;
run;

data want;
set have;
by person_id recu_day;
retain adm;
if first.person_id then adm=0;
if first.recu_day then adm+1;
run;
```